# Is a spell still active if a character does not sustain it one turn?

Tags: spellcasting, pathfinder-2e

On round one, K'zard the wizard casts Flaming Sphere.

On round two, K'zard doesn't sustain the spell.

Can K'zard sustain the spell on round three?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### No, if the caster doesn't use the *[Sustain a Spell](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=73)* action on a spell with sustained duration the spell ends at the end of that turn.

About [sustaining spells](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=292):

> If the spell’s duration is “sustained,” it lasts until the end of your next turn unless you use a Sustain a Spell action on that turn to extend the duration of that spell.

I think this is pretty self explanatory. In your example:

1st round - K'zard the wizard casts *Flaming Sphere*.

2nd round - K'zard the wizard has to choose whether to use the  *Sustain a Spell* action or not. If he doesn't use the action the spell ends when this turn ends. If he does use the action, the spell continues until the next round.

3rd round - If K'zard the wizard chose not to sustain the spell on the previous round, there's no spell anymore, he can't try to sustain something that isn't there. If he did sustain it, he can choose whether to use the *Sustain a Spell* action again or not. Repeat this process on following rounds.

Comment: Probably change your title to be a little more descriptive; the question title and last line are different and someone reading straight through from the question to your answer would be confused by "No, it isn't.". I'd personally use "Duration: sustained spells end after your next turn if not sustained"